# Cart price rule to exclude multiple SKU's

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm not a dev and have very limited experience in M2 but I'm in need of some help, if possible?

I need to create a 'cart price rule' to exclude multiple SKU's but have no idea how to do this.

So far I have only created a 10% off all items discount so I have never needed to edit 'conditions'

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please initially refer to https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html

Answer (score 0):

as per your Screenshot. You did correctly.

What is problem now??

after editing rule you must need to run indexing command

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`